# In Eclispe, disable the "Find Next" text being replaced when highlighting text

Tags: eclipse

Often when I'm searching through a document with eclipse, I will hit the shortcut for `Find Next` and the cursor will just to the next match of the text I've last searched for.  However, if I highlight text to copy while doing this, it changes the search text to be whatever I highlighted, so now when I use `Find Next` it searches for the text I had highlighted.

Is there a way to disable automatically setting the `find` text when it's highlighted?  I've looked though preferences, but I couldn't find anything related to this.

Comment: Why you need to highlight different text during finding next text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...if I highlight text to copy while doing this, it changes the search
>   text to be whatever I highlighted, so now when I use Find Next it
>   searches for the text I had highlighted

Right, and that's [exactly how it's defined to work](https://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-menu-edit.htm):

*Find Next  Finds the next occurrence of **the currently selected text**. Editor only.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>*

That's pretty fundamental, and I doubt if there is any way to prevent that.

> Is there a way to disable automatically setting the find text when
>   it's highlighted

I don't think you can do any explicit disabling, but if you already have a **Find/Replace** dialog open then selecting some text in the editor will not update the "find text" (i.e. **Find** field) in the Find/Replace dialog.

So a solution/workaround is to use **Find** (**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>**) instead of **Find Next** for your text searching.

Change your approach for text searching as follows:

- Select your text to search for as before.
- Instead of pressing **Find Next** (**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>**), press **Find/Replace** (**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>**) which will open the **Find/Replace** dialog, with your selected text shown in the **Find** field.
- Repeatedly click the **Find** button (shortcut is **<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>**) to find the next match.
- During your search you can safely select other text multiple times, and even copy and paste it, without it impacting your search.

A minor drawback to this approach is that you must have the **Find/Replace** dialog open while searching, and re-select it if you choose to select and/or modify text in the edit window, but apart from that it will achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: That's disappointing.  Maybe my issue is that the Find/Replace dialog is floating for me, and so I always want to get rid of it after I've entered my search text.  Once I'm back at my editor, I'll attempt to dock the floating dialog which should at least get it out of my way, and since it will still be open hopefully it won't be changed by highlighting.  Either way, you've answered my question.  Thanks.